# Prevent cmake to run cpack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a CMake project where I want to prevent `make package` to do anything more than print a message on some platforms.

I know how to add a message, even a fatal one, but that runs during cmake-generation, not during builds. Do I have to resort to some `add_custom_command`? And that won't give me what I want, since that creates a new build target...

How can I override the `package` target for some platforms to just show a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shu pointed out, you can do something like this:

```
if (! WIN32)
    include(cpack)
else()
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0037 OLD)
    add_custom_target(package
        #add dependencies on other targets here
        #[[DEPENDS install]]
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "custom target for non windows platforms!"
)
endif()
```

Note that by default, you will not be allowed to override reserved targets like **test** and **package**. We are turning off that policy here to write our own package target.

Answer (score 1):

why include cpack in your cmake list at all?

In order for a cmake project to have a cpack controlled package target, your project should include a line like:

```
include(CPack)
```

and also setting up some cpack-related properties. If you don't want that, you can just take out that line.

Comment: "on some platforms", but I could do the include conditionally, of course.

Comment: So do you want the source code to generate a make file that fails with a target package that does not do anything if you are say on Linux? As in you are not talking about say a deb installer ( the result of a cpack package) that refuses to install if the platform is say 32 bit, right?

Comment: Right. No, I want the target 'package' to either print a message (preferably) or not exist at all. So http://stackoverflow.com/a/38119685/204658 is pretty much was I was looking for.